# Trying to extract links from fetching link from csv file into request.get but getting " TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable "

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import csv

import pandas as pd

links = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\hindustan_pages.csv',encoding = 'latin',dtype=str)

for i in range(1,3):

      link = links.iloc[i,0]

      r = requests.get(link)

      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

      div = soup.find('div',{"id":"company_list_grid"})
      for links in div.find_all('th',{"id":"c_name"}):
          link = links.find('a')
          print("https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad" + link['href'][2:])
```

getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\hindustanyellowpages.py",
>   line 8, in
>
> ```
> link = links.iloc[i,0]
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

help me please to sort out this.

Comment: i have send you the csv file plase check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, but first:

1) When pandas reads in the csv file, it's assuming you have a header. So row 1 in your csv actually never would get processed because that gets stored as the column name, so you'd need to add a parameter to tell pandas that there are no headers `header=None`. Also just as a note, not sure if you realize it or not, but the indices start at 0. So your code as is, is starting actually with the link at row 2 of the dataframe. If you want it to start at row 1, you'd need `range(0,2)`

2) the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` is raised because `links` which is storing your dataframe to iterate over, gets overwritten at `for links in div.find_all('th',{"id":"c_name"}):`. So when it goes to the 2nd row of your `links` dataframe, it no longer is a dataframe, but rather an element in your `div.find_all('th',{"id":"c_name"})` tags. To fix this, we'll just rename your `links` dataframe as `links_df`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Renamed to links_df and added header=None
links_df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\hindustan_pages.csv',encoding = 'latin',dtype=str, header=None)

#for i, row in links_df.iterrows():  <---- if you want it to do the whole dataframe, you can simply use .iterrows instead of for i in range()
for i in range(1,3):
    link = links_df.iloc[i,0] #<--- refers to a row in your links_df
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

    div = soup.find('div',{"id":"company_list_grid"})
    for links in div.find_all('th',{"id":"c_name"}):
        link = links.find('a')
        print("https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad" + link['href'][2:])
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Hetal-Mandap-Decorators/Satellite
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Radhe-Krishna-Event-Management/Bapunagar
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Amiraj-Decorators/Maninagar
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Hiral-Handicraft/Saijpur-Bogha
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/S-D-Traders/Teen-Darwaja
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Agro-Net-Plast/Kathwada
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Shree-Krishna-Suppliers/Naroda
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Bulakhidas-Vitthaldas/Panchkuva
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Nagindas-AND-Sons-(Patva)/Relief-Road
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/New-Rahul-Electricals-OR-Dhruv-Light-Decoration-AND-Sound-System/Subhash-Bridge
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Bhairavi-Craft/Thaltej
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Saath-Sangath-Party-Plot/Rakanpur
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Poonam-Light-Decoration-And-Electricals/Naroda
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Muku-Enterprise/Isanpur
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Malaviya-Decoration-Service/Nikol
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Hariprabha-Enterprises/Paldi
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Festo-Craft/Thaltej
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Jay-Jognimata-Decoration/Kubernagar
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Maruti-Decorators/Ranip
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Krishna-Light-and-Decoration/Gandhi-Road
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Shree-Ambika-Light-Decoration/Ghatlodiya
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/R-S-Power-House/Gandhi-Road
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/New-Amit-Stores/Paldi
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Gayatri-Cetera-s-and-Decoration/Ranip
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Poonam-lights-and-decoration/Navrangpura
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Shree-Ambica-Engg-Works/Naroda
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Vedant-Industries/Vatva-Gidc
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Honest-Traders/Narol
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Sai-Samarth-Industries/Nana-Chiloda
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/R-N-Industries/Odhav
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Jay-Ambe-Enterprise/S-G-Road
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Satyam-Enterprise/Narol
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Maniar-And-Co/Rakhial
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Shiv-Shakti-Plastic-Industries/Amraivadi
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Dinesh-Engineering-Works/Kathwada
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/MARUTI-ENGINEERS-OR-MARUTI-SAND-BLASTING/Odhav
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Cranetech-Equipments/Vatva
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Suyog-Engineering-AND-Fabricators/Chhatral-GIDC
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Sanghvii-Conveyors/Thaltej
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Siddh-Kripa-Steel-Fab/Kathwada
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Ashirvad-Industries/Vatva-Gidc
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/G-I-Lokhandwala/Chandola
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/M-P-Electrical-Engineering--OR--M-P-Crane/Naroda-Gidc
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Krishna-Enterprise/Geeta-Mandir
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Nmtg-Mechtrans-Techniques-Pvt-Ltd/Naroda-Gidc
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Shree-Balaad-Handling-Works/Odhav
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/DLM-Enterprise/Vastral
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Alfa-Engineers--OR--Everest-Sanitary/Amaraivadi
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Parv-Engineering-Equipments/Vatva
https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/Vikrant-Equipments/Kathwada
```

**Additional:**

use:

```
for i, row in links_df.head(10).iterrows():
    link = links_df.iloc[i,0]
```

or

```
for i, row in links_df.iloc[:10].iterrows():
    link = links_df.iloc[i,0]
```

Comment: thank you. very kind of you to explain me. as you say i can do this " for i, row in links_df.iterrows():" so here we have to give range 1 to 10 in link_df.iterrows(1,10) or something else.

Comment: Nope no range goes in there. Simply just links_df.iterrows() will do the whole data frame, all rows. If you wanted only first 10 rows, you could do link_df.head(10).iterrows() or link_df.iloc[:10].iterrows  also remember index starts at 0. So if you did links_iloc[1:10].iterrows() this would start in row 2. To start row 1 you’d want [0:10] or simply [:10]

Comment: And wouldn’t need the for I in range part. Just replace that with the for i, row in links_df.iterrows():

Comment: i tried this  " for i, row in links_df.iterrows(): " ,but which element should i use to put in requests.get() . i or row ?

Comment: getting error while trying " link_df.head(10).iterrows() OR link_df.iloc[:10] "

Comment: I actually have a typo there: should be `link_df.head(10).iterrows()` or `link_df.iloc[:10].iterrows()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
link = df.link.iloc[i]
```

If i am not mistaking your df is links so

```
link = links.link.iloc[i]
```

Let me know if this helps